# Curl not returning all headers

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I am using Curl in PHP to call an [API](http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/user-authentication).

According to their [documentation](http://help.themoviedb.org/kb/api/authentication-request-token), they are returning "Authentication-Callback" within the returned page's header.

It works perfectly when I paste the URL into the browser, but Curl seems to leave it out.

Here is my code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/token/new?api_key=[MY_API_KEY]&language=en');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Here is the returned header

```
Array
    (
        [url] => http://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/token/new?api_key=[MY_API_KEY]&language=en&
        [content_type] => application/json;charset=utf-8
        [http_code] => 200
        [header_size] => 470
        [request_size] => 137
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0.109
        [namelookup_time] => 0
        [connect_time] => 0.047
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.047
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 116
        [speed_download] => 1064
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => 116
        [upload_content_length] => 0
        [starttransfer_time] => 0.109
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

As far as I can tell, everything is right.  Curl returns the data that I need perfectly, just not the correct headers.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I know this solves nothing, but just wanted to point out that if you're able to use a wrapper around curl, such as [pecl_http](http://us.php.net/http), things like those might be much pleasant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing right now is getting stored information about the header via [`curl_getinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) which only gets the information in the OPT list on that page.

What you should do instead is to return the header and then manually separate it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// The rest of your options
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Since the end of the header is always delimited by two newlines
$output = explode("\n\n", $output, 2);
$header = $output[0];
$content = $output[1];
```

This is more work but will get you the real headers.

Answer (score 2):

This is my code to do what phsource has suggested the headers are put into the $headers array

```
# Extract headers from response
preg_match_all('%HTTP/\\d\\.\\d.*?(\\r\\n|\\n){2,}%si', $curl_result, $header_matches);
$headers = preg_split('/\\r\\n/', str_replace("\r\n\r\n",'',array_pop($header_matches[0])));

# Convert headers into an associative array
if(is_array($headers))
{
  foreach ($headers as $header)
  {
    preg_match('#(.*?)\:\s(.*)#', $header, $header_matches);
    if(isset($header_matches[1]))
    {
      $headers[$header_matches[1]] = $header_matches[2];
      $headers['lowercase'][strtolower($header_matches[1])] = $header_matches[2];
    }
  }
}

# Remove the headers from the response body
$curl_result = preg_replace('%HTTP/\\d\\.\\d.*?(\\r\\n|\\n){2,}%si','',$curl_result);
```

you may want to replace \r\n with PHP_EOL as you see fit